# How to use th:selected with HashMap entrySet() in Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, thymeleaf, html-select

I tried putting selected inside the empty option and also th:selected with after th:text, neither worked for me, Here is my code:

```
<select name="uploadDate"style=" width:100%;" id="uploadDate" class="form-control select2">
        <option></option>
        <option th:each="uploadDateMenu : ${uploadDateMenu.entrySet()}"
                th:value="${uploadDateMenu.key}" 
                th:text="${uploadDateMenu.value}">
      </option>
</select>
```

I tried putting the code:

```
th:selected="${uploadDateMenu.key == 2}"
```

after "th:text" inside the option tag but it's not working. The data is in the key value pair. Where the key is 2 and the value corresponding to it is "Last 2 days".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
th:selected="${uploadDateMenu.getKey() == 2}"
```

Or if it doesn`t work, rewrite it like this:

```
   <option th:each="uploadDateMenuEntry : ${uploadDateMenu.entrySet()}"
                th:value="${uploadDateMenuEntry.key}" 
                th:text="${uploadDateMenuEntry.value}"
                th:selected="${uploadDateMenu.get(2)}">

      </option>
```

Comment: Hi peter i forgot putting code. Thanks for undertstanding. Now I have put the code, please answer.

Comment: Do you know the id of the uploadDateMenu which you want to be as default one?

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked! I appreciate for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help!